# It moved in a straight line with sparkling track.What could it be?

Tags: movement

Today I saw something that passed like a jet. But am sure it's not so because jet will leave a long track of its passage. It moved in a straight line with sparkling track and what I saw was observed even from  200kms away from my destination. What could it be?[image]

Comment: Where, when? Did you see the object moving? Was it bright and fast? (so that only last a couple of seconds) You say it "passed like a jet" that normally take longer than that. Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: *because jet will leave a long track* Not true - this totally depends on the circumstances at the planes altitude (temp, humidity, wind).

Comment: Once I saw a meteor at might and it looked as sparking as in a cartoon. The many I saw were just traces but that one was much more round headed leaving sparks. Perhaps it was the same in your case. But it wasn't lasting more than 1 second

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a jet contrail. Not all contrails are persistent, and a high altitude jet can be seen over a great distance.

A fireball may leave a trail, but if it does, then it is likely to persist for as long or longer than a jet contrail. A fireball appears to move much faster than a jet, crossing the sky in a few seconds. It also appears to be very bright.

The image and description both point to this being a jet.